# Spring 3, Hibernate 4 AutoWired sessionFactory with Generic DAO

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-generic-dao

Using Spring MVC 3 & Hibernate 4 I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

com.daniel.rr.dao.common.DAOImpl.getSession(DAOImpl.java:22)
com.daniel.rr.dao.common.DAOImpl.save(DAOImpl.java:27)
com.daniel.rr.controller.HelloController.printWelcome(HelloController.java:30)
```

This is the relevant spring configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.daniel.rr.model</value>
            <value>com.daniel.rr.dao</value>
            <value>com.daniel.rr.dao.common</value>
            <value>com.daniel.rr.controller</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rr" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />

</bean>



<bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Generic DAO:

```
public interface DAO<T> {

    T save(T t);
    void delete(T t);
} 

@Transactional
public abstract class DAOImpl<T> implements DAO<T> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public T save(T t) {
        getSession().persist(t);
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T t) {
        getSession().delete(t);
    }
}
```

AccountDAO:

```
public class AccountDAO extends DAOImpl<Account> implements DAO<Account> {

}
```

MVC Controller:

```
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        //System.out.println("is null? " + sessionFactory);

        AccountDAO dao = new AccountDAO();
        Account account = new Account();

        account.setUsername("hello");
        account.setPassword("test");

        dao.save(account);

        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I've searched thru StackOverflow and Google but I cannot find anything that helps.
I've tried using a Transaction on DAOImpl.save(T t) but it still has the same issue.

```
public T save(T t) {
        Transaction tr = getSession().getTransaction();
        tr.begin();

        getSession().persist(t);

        tr.commit();
        return t;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotations are not inherited.

Add the transactional annotation to the concrete dao, not the abstract class.

[You might like this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002836/spring-generic-dao-class-name/15002922#15002922)

Comment: Thanks! Found the solution.